# Can the word petrify be used correctly in the sentences below?

Tags: word-usage

Can the word petrify be used correctly in the sentences below?

> - He was petrified with exhaustion!
> - He was so petrified he slept without moving a muscle.

Comment: Had he trodden on a stonefish?

Comment: Seriously, though one of AHDEL's definitions does seemingly allow 'petrified with exhaustion', the expression is non-idiomatic (4 Google hits), and its use would sound unnatural. _He was dead tired. So tired, he slept like a log._  But do clear up the difference between 'muscle' and 'mussel'.

Comment: You can be petrified with *fear, astonishment, grief,* and maybe *indecision.* But *petrified with exhaustion* doesn't really work.

Comment: It's most idiomatic (in the US) to be petrified due to some strong emotion, vs, eg, exhaustion.  (Though a clever writer might turn a good phrase using "petrified with indifference".)

Comment: You can be petrified by anything that makes you stiff and unresponsive - stone-like. (The use is figurative, of course.) Some drugs, for instance (stoned again).

Answer (score 1):

To petrify is to (either literally or figuratively) turn to stone, to become hard or rigid. The usual usage with respect to people is "petrified with fear" or "petrified with fright", as in the song "I Wonder What The King Is Doing Tonight" from the musical "Camelot" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rggnZ1nmV9M:

> A warrior who's so calm in battle,
>
> Even his armor doesn't rattle,
>
> Faces a woman petrified with fright?
>
> Right!

When exhausted, one cannot move because one's muscles are limp, not because they are rigid, so you would say

"He was limp with exhaustion."

And suggesting that a person could sleep with all muscles tightened makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

No. To "petrify" is to make someone frozen *with fear* (or to literally turn organic matter into stone). Those two usages would both be incorrect.

Comment: You're missing the other, less rigorous sense given by eg AHDEL and [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/petrify): << **petrify** 2. to make or become dull, unresponsive, insensitive, etc; deaden. >> It is far better to give answers supported by references from accepted authorities.

Comment: Interesting, I must have missed that definition when I looked it up at several different respected dictionaries. Source, please?

Comment: You've also missed the sources. I've already given them, and quoted and hotlinked to one.

Comment: petrified with exhaustion does not make sense maybe you should check that answer.

Comment: The word simply means *turned to stone*. It can be used figuratively, of course, to capture the idea that something or some has become stone-like in some respect(s).

Answer (score -1):

Being petrified, means that you cannot move, you are turned to stone. Thus you can't simply be *petrified with exhaustion*, you need to define first the appropriate context, eg. if the person is standing, the sentence is nonsensical, because holding the pose requires energy. However

> He was so tired. He lay petrified with exhaustion. He slept all night without moving a muscle.

is perfectly fine. Because he is lying down devoid of energy.

Secondly you cannot be more or less petrified. Either you are petrified, or you are not. So saying "He was *so* petrified" makes no sense either. But

> He was petrified, he slept without moving a muscle.

is fine, although, I might choose to put "petrified" at the end of the sentence, so as not to let people misunderstand and think first that he was afraid. Or perhaps make it a simile:

> He was like petrified, slept without moving a muscle.